# Trusted certificate for internal company app (.Net Framework)

Tags: .net, deployment

Is there a way to issue a certificate to sign an internal company app (.Net Framework) so that it is trusted and does not raise warnings during deployment?

Is there a way for example for users to add/trust a self-signed certificate? The Windows Defender keeps raising a warning every time the app is installed and updated and users have to manually click to run. I have tried to add the certificate to a user's trusted certificates manually.

Comment: You can use a private CA for this. Either ADCS in Windows Server (free if you already have a licence for that) or an open-source PKI alternative. If you have a AD domain you can distribute the root certificate using Group Policy. Then issue yourself a Code Signing certificate, and sign your deployment in Visual Studio.